# Can anybody tell me the meaning of a punctuation character?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a code that I don't know the meaning of a punctuation:

```py
train_data_file = "./zhengqi_train.txt"
train_data = pd.read_csv(train_data_file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8'
```

I don't know why we should add `./` in `train_data_file` in Python coding

Comment: `./` = current directory. It's a relative path, rather than writing the full thing out like `/users/zicheng/dev/zhengqi_train.txt`.

Comment: you **don't need** to add that for `pandas.read_csv`

Answer (score 1):

By itself, a dot (`.`) means "the current directory".

The slash (`/`) is the usual delimeter between directory names and filenames. However, if a slash is the  first character then this is an absolute path, not a relative path. More on that in a moment.

So `"./zhengqi_train.txt"` means:

- starting from the current directory
- read or write the file in that directory called `zhengqi_train.txt`

Relative paths always start from the current directory.
Absolute paths always start from the root directory, written `/` for *nix (UNIX and Linux).

Similarly, `"./a/b/c"` means:

- starting from the current directory
- traverse the directory called `a`
- within `a`, traverse the directory called `b`
- within `b`, read or write the file called `c`

Finally, `"a/./c"` means:

- (starting from the current directory is implied because this is a relative path)
- traverse the directory called `a`
- ignore the `.` (bizarre, but true)
- within `a`, read or write the file called `c`

Bonus:
`..` means "parent directory"

So "../b/c" means:

- starting from the parent directory
- traverse the directory called `b` (this is a sibling directory to the current directory)
- within `b`, read or write the file called `c`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you, this is not about `Python`, this is about all programming language.

`./` indicates the current directory, where your source code exists.
`../` indicates the parent directory of your source code.
`../../` indicates parent of parent directory of your source code.

All there notations are in respect of your source code location.

So now, if the file you want to read is in the same directory, then you can use both `./` or not. Why, because the operating system will take it as the home directory and present you the file.

But for convention, you should always use `./`, because sometimes, the code may break in different OS.

That's it. Hope you understand